# How is $x^\frac{9}{4} \cdot x^\frac{1}{2} = x^\frac{11}{4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How is $x^\frac{9}{4}  \cdot x^\frac{1}{2} = x^\frac{11}{4}$?

I don't really understand it.

Comment: $$ x^n \cdot x^m = x^{n + m } $$ In your case, $1/2 = 2/4$ and so $9/4 + 2/4 = 11/4 $.

Comment: @Anonaki ok thank you I did not think you could convert the denominators like that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$x^{9/4}=(x^{1/4})^9.$$ 
$$x^{1/2}=(x^{1/4})^2.$$  Letting $y=x^{1/4}$, we get:

$$x^{9/4}\cdot x^{1/2} = y^9\cdot y^2=y^{11} = (x^{1/4})^{11}=x^{11/4}$$

Comment: Didn't downvote, but to me this seems overly complex -- just reminding the exponent rule and that 9/4+1/2 = 11/4 seems sufficient. This answer doesn't make totally clear (on first glance at least) that you are just adding the exponents

Comment: I'm showing why $x^a\cdot x^b = x^{a+b}$ when $a,b$ rational. That does need to be shown. Anyway, the other answer gave your approach, and it got $5$ downvotes, too. (That answerer deleted his answer.) @ZachEffman

Comment: The OP accepted that simple explanation in the comments. I also didn't downvote this answer, and I agree that the negative response seems unreasonable.

Comment: @ZachEffman That doesn't mean this is a wrong answer. I have never seen this behavior, and I'm not buying that explanation. Somebody is engaging in some sort of bad behavior here.

Answer (score 6):

Use the exponent rule $x^a\cdot x^b = x^{a + b}$ with $a = 9/4$ and $b = 1/2$. Since $b = 2/4$, $a + b = 9/4 + 2/4 = 11/4$.

Comment: I'm curious to see what happens...

Comment: no need to write an answer for this question. you can just answer it in the comments.

Comment: I really don't know why people are downvoting this like crazy, nor why the question has 5 upvotes. I think someone is experimenting with something illicit here.

Comment: I did downvote both answers because they could have been just answered in comment box.(Like my answer)

Comment: @Anonaki, the concensus on meta is that you shouldn't leave questions open with answers in the comments: the comment should be made an answer and accepted so the question is closed: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/what-should-one-do-when-ones-question-has-been-answered-in-the-comments/1149#1149 http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments

Comment: @Anonaki Then you don't understand the site, if you think answering in comments is enough. The point is to create an archive of answers, and comments are not the place for finding answers. As for my complicated answer, some people don't know why $x^{a}\cdot x^{b}=x^{a+b}$ when $a,b$ rational, but it is "obvious" when $a,b$ integers. Since kobe's answer already existed, I gave a different answer which only used the integer version.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I just find it funny that the question was receiving so many upvotes, while at the same time our answers were receiving so many downvotes.  I'm upvoting your answer. :)

Comment: @kobe That's why I wondered if something odd/illicit was happening. Not sure what. But I think it is more likely that, for some reason, this question made the StackExchange front page, and we got lots of newbs here.

Comment: I think given the vitriol coming from Anonaki, that second explanation is much more likely

Comment: @ZachEffman Not sure I'd call Anonaki's posts"vitriol." He's wrong about answers in comments, of course, but he's also not a newb. At least, not in the sense I meant - somebody who'd literally never been to this site.

Comment: The comment about your answer being terrible and wishing the site allowed multiple downvotes has since been removed, I see

Comment: @ZachEffman I'm not sure, but it might've been removed because I flagged for being non-constructive.

Comment: It certainly wasn't